# Datastax Java driver can't authenticate against Cassandra PasswordAuthenticator when logging into a cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-2.0

Using a small test Java program like below, I can login to a single Cassandra 2.0.1 node and execute a query with no errors:

```
$ java -classpath .:cassandra-driver-core-1.0.4.jar DriverTester 127.0.0.1 myusername mypassword
Got test query result 1ba51260-5b6e-11e3-8f1c-7dd8c1a15c4b
```

Supplying a wrong password fails with a "Username and/or password are incorrect" error, as expected.

But when trying the same program against a node that belongs to a three-node cluster, using the right credentials, I get a somewhat confusing "Required key 'username' is missing" message:

```
$ java -classpath .:cassandra-driver-core-1.0.4.jar DriverTester cluster-node1 myusername mypassword
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.AuthenticationException: Authentication error on host /62.142.90.104: Required key 'username' is missing
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.initializeTransport(Connection.java:171)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:132)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:60)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Connection$Factory.open(Connection.java:419)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.tryConnect(ControlConnection.java:205)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:168)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:81)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:773)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.access$100(Cluster.java:706)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:79)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.<init>(Cluster.java:66)
    at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Builder.build(Cluster.java:687)
    at fi.elisa.viihde.stats.DriverTester.openDatastaxSession(DriverTester.java:40)
    at fi.elisa.viihde.stats.DriverTester.doTest(DriverTester.java:28)
    at fi.elisa.viihde.stats.DriverTester.main(DriverTester.java:15)
```

Why is this happening?

The credentials are correct, since supplying the same ones to `cqlsh` works without problems:

```
$ cqlsh cluster-node1 -u myusername -p mypassword
Connected to cluster-node1 at xx.xx.xx.xx:9160.
[cqlsh 4.0.1 | Cassandra 2.0.1 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.37.0]
Use HELP for help.
cqlsh>
```

Test program code:

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;

public class DriverTester {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        try {
            doTest(args);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public static void doTest(String... args) {
        String[] hostnames = args[0].split(",");
        String username = args[1];
        String password = args[2];

        Cluster.Builder clusterBuilder = Cluster.builder()
                .addContactPoints(hostnames).withPort(9042)
                .withCredentials(username, password);
        Session session = clusterBuilder.build().connect();
        System.out.println("Got test query result " +
                session.execute("select now() from system.local").one().getUUID(0));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrading to Datastax driver 2.0.0-rc2 fixes this problem, as does upgrading Cassandra from 2.0.1 to 2.0.3 (or possibly 2.0.2). For the latter, see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6233